# Sum is not adding float variables. It is concantenating the values in XSLT

Tags: xslt

When i try to sum a float variables it results in a concatenated string of all variables instead of the sum. I don't know how to proceed.

```
<xsl:for-each select="G_1/G_2/FILE_FRAGMENT/SLO_CALPERS_PAYROLL/Person_DG">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/Input_Value_Base_Name= 'Amount' and Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/Amount != 0">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(format-number(Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/Amount, '0.00'))"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:for-each>
```

Expected

```
<results>23.46</results>
```

Actual Results

```
<results>0.9311.2111.32</results>
```

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="G_1/G_2/FILE_FRAGMENT/SLO_CALPERS_PAYROLL/Person_DG">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/Input_Value_Base_Name= 'Amount' and Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/Amount != 0">
           <xsl:value-of select="sum(format-number(Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/Amount, '0.00'))"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

Comment: That is the code I'm using

Comment: Please edit your question and insert any code samples there in a well formatted and readable way, we need to see both the relevant XSLT and the relevant XML input sample.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first time using stackoverflow. So I had to figure that out

Comment: Usually you would call the `sum` function first with an argument that is a node-set or sequence of items containing numbers and then you would call the `format-number` function on the result of the `sum()` call. So far you have not shown the relevant XML sample so it is hard to tell which values you have and whether the used XPath expressions are right. I would suggest to cut all samples to a minimum to demonstrate the problem but allow others to easily reproduce it.

Comment: sum() applied to a set of strings should either give NaN (1.0) or an error (2.0). You're applying sum() to the result of format-number(), and format-number delivers strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took wrong order of operations. You should:

- First sum `Amount` values.
- Then apply the required formatting (to the just computed sum).

So, for my example data:

```
<main>
  <Amount>1.7</Amount>
  <Amount>3.3</Amount>
</main>
```

I executed the following script:

```
<xsl:template match="main">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <Sum><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(Amount), '0.00')"/></Sum>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(+ the *identity template*), getting:

```
<main>
    <Amount>1.7</Amount>
    <Amount>3.3</Amount>
    <Sum>5.00</Sum>
</main>
```

Another flaw in your code is that you put the summing instruction
**inside a loop** (and *choose*).

This way, each time your code finds the "allowed" *Amount* (!= 0)
it sums and outputs **just the one value**.

The result is that you got concatenated **individual** values.

My advice is:

- Drop the loop altogether.
- Also *choose* has little sense, as zeroes are not likely to change the sum.
- In your code, add the proper initial part of *XPath*
  (*G_1/G_2/FILE_FRAGMENT/SLO_CALPERS_PAYROLL/Person_DG/Run_Results_Record/Run_Results_DG/Run_Results/*) to the *select* clause.

Comment: Thank you so much! I dropped the loop and the it's adding up!